# Mocking only two methods in class for unit testing Moq and XUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Hope you are doing great.

WE have service which calls method  `GetUserAccountNo()`   in  turn call other two (`GetUser`, `CreateUser`) in that service .
we are using Moq and XUnit for testing
Can anybody let me know how can I mock only the `GetUser` and `CreateUser` and write unit test for the `GetUserAccountNo`?

I can see some people saying about making the methods as `virtual`.
Here in  this case all the methods are in same class and from same interface and `public` as well

Please find the code snippet

```
public int GetUserAccountNo (string id)
{
    if (GetUser(id)!=null )
    {
        return GetUser(id).AccountNo;
    }
    else
    {
        return CreateUser(id).AccountNo;
    }
}


public User GetUser(string id)
{
    //Get from  userAPi
    return new User();
}

public User CreateUser(string id)
{
    //Create from userAPi using  http request
    return new User();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Generally you wouldn't mock parts of your SUT (system under test). Normally you would inject the user API into your service and mock that. Nevertheless it can be done.

Mark the methods as virtual and mock them as you normally would; working LINQPad example:

```
void Main()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var existingUser = fixture.Create<User>();
    var newUser = fixture.Create<User>();

    var fooMock = new Mock<FooService>();
    fooMock.Setup(x => x.GetUser(It.Is<string>(y => y.Equals(existingUser.Id)))).Returns(() => existingUser);
    fooMock.Setup(x => x.CreateUser(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => newUser);
    var foo = fooMock.Object;

    foo.GetUserAccountNo(existingUser.Id).Should().Be(existingUser.AccountNo);
    foo.GetUserAccountNo(newUser.Id).Should().Be(newUser.AccountNo);
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class FooService
{
    public FooService() { }

    public int GetUserAccountNo(string id)
    {
        if (GetUser(id) != null)
        {
            return GetUser(id).AccountNo;
        }
        else
        {
            return CreateUser(id).AccountNo;
        }
    }

    public virtual User GetUser(string id)
    {
        //Get from User API
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual User CreateUser(string id)
    {

        //Get from User API
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int AccountNo { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe there is a good reason in your case but it's generally not a great approach; you've modified your SUT for a test; you're not leveraging one of the great benefits of dependency injection - the ability to substitute a dependency with something else; and, as you're mocking an implementation, you'll also need to satisfy the constructor requirements - for brevity I have used a parameterless constructor.

Provided we can inject and mock the user API, then the following would be the normal approach:

```
void Main()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var existingUser = fixture.Create<User>();
    var newUser = fixture.Create<User>();

    var userApiMock = new Mock<IUserApi>();
    userApiMock.Setup(x => x.GetUser(It.Is<string>(y => y.Equals(existingUser.Id)))).Returns(() => existingUser);
    userApiMock.Setup(x => x.CreateUser(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => newUser);
    var userApi = userApiMock.Object;

    var foo = new FooService(userApi);

    foo.GetUserAccountNo(existingUser.Id).Should().Be(existingUser.AccountNo);
    foo.GetUserAccountNo(newUser.Id).Should().Be(newUser.AccountNo);
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public interface IUserApi
{
    User GetUser(string id);

    User CreateUser(string id);
}

public class FooService
{
    IUserApi _userApi;

    public FooService(IUserApi userApi)
    {
        _userApi = userApi;
    }

    public int GetUserAccountNo(string id)
    {
        if (GetUser(id) != null)
        {
            return GetUser(id).AccountNo;
        }
        else
        {
            return CreateUser(id).AccountNo;
        }
    }

    public User GetUser(string id)
    {
        return _userApi.GetUser(id);
    }

    public User CreateUser(string id)
    {
        return _userApi.CreateUser(id);
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int AccountNo { get; set; }
}
```